# Someone signed in to Google services using my Yahoo email. What should I do now?

Tags: google-account, security, yahoo-mail

I don't remember having my Yahoo email used in any of Google services, but today someone just signed in using my Yahoo e-mail. I might just did use Google services with Yahoo email a long time ago.

Here's what he did to my account (according to the notifications I got in my Yahoo email):

- Signed in from somewhere using Firefox
- Changed the password of my Google Account (which uses my Yahoo email)
- Set his own Gmail address and  primary username with a new/another Google account (b************d@gmail.com)

Now what should I do?

I tried using [Google account recovery](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/) but it says "No account is found with that email address" (which is, my Yahoo e-mail).

Is it safe to change my Yahoo account? I'm afraid every activity in my Yahoo account now will be mailed to this offender. Is there a way to know what service he's using? Should I do something else?

Comment: Are you 100% sure (from looking at its headers, etc.) that the email you received is from Yahoo and not fake?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/

Fill this form out.

Also always have two step verification set on accounts, that way no one can alter your personal accounts, unless they have your cell phone as well.

Comment: That's the problem, it says my Yahoo e-mail (which is used to login to Google service) is not found. "No account found with that email address," it says.

Comment: @deathlock Not sure I follow. You "Google service" account, didn't have a Gmail address, but just used your yahoo.com address as the username? It sounds like you don't need to recover your "Google service" account, but are only concerned with securing your yahoo.com account. If so, and Google is reporting no record of your yahoo.com account, you shouldn't need to do anything. Having said that it wouldn't be a bad idea to change your Yahoo account's password and add two step verification to it.